# the output is not giving the required result. what to do?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

//this program intends to do matrix multiplication
int
main()
{
  START:
    ;
    int r1, c1, r2, c2;

    printf("this is a multiplication matrix program\n");

    printf("please enter the number of rows for matrix 1 \n");
    scanf("%d", &r1);

    printf("please enter the number of columns for matrix 1 \n");
    scanf("%d", &c1);

    printf("please enter the number of rows for matrix 2 \n");
    scanf("%d", &r2);

    printf("please enter the number of columns for matrix 2 \n");
    scanf("%d", &c2);

    //creation of matrix 1
    int a[r1][c1];
    int (*ptr1)[r1][c1] = &a;

    //Storing the elements in the matrix 1, This is working fine
    int t1, t2;

    for (t1 = 0; t1 < r1; t1++) {
        for (t2 = 0; t2 < c1; t2++) {
            printf("Please enter the (%d,%d) element of the array", t1, t2);
            scanf("%d", ptr1[t1][t2]);
        }
    }
    //creation of matrix 2
    int b[r2][c2];
    int (*ptr2)[r2][c2] = &b;
    int t3, t4;

    //Storing the elements in the matrix 2, This is working fine
    for (t3 = 0; t3 < r2; t3++) {
        for (t4 = 0; t4 < c2; t4++) {
            printf("Please enter the (%d,%d) element of the array", t3, t4);
            scanf("%d", ptr2[t3][t4]);
        }
    }
    //Till now the input has been taken, after this rest of code intended to
    //be executed by the compiler without any input.

    //If the basic condition for matrix multiplication is satisfied, proceed
    //else re-enter the values.
    if (c1 == r2) {
        int t5, t6;

        /*Here sum is the new matrix which is the product of matrix
        multiplication intended to store the individual values of the matrix
        elements.*/
        int sum[2][3];

        for (t5 = 0; t5 < r1; t5++) {
            for (t6 = 0; t6 < c2; t6++) {
                // applying the formula for individual element calculation by
                // matrix multiplication.
                int sum2;
                int k = 0;

                for (k = 0; k < r2; k++) {
                    sum2 += (*ptr1[t5][k]) * (*ptr2[k][t6]);
                }
                // value calculated is stored in the variable inteded for its
                // storage.
                sum[t5][t6] = sum2;
                // reset value of sum2 for next iteration.
                sum2 = 0;

            }
        }

        //printing value of elements of the resultant matrix.After entering 1
        //as every single element of both matrices, the results are expected
        //to be all 2.
        printf(" Element 1 is %d\n", sum[0][0]);
        printf(" Element 2 is %d\n", sum[0][1]);
        printf(" Element 3 is %d\n", sum[0][2]);
        printf(" Element 4 is %d\n", sum[1][0]);
        printf(" Element 5 is %d\n", sum[1][1]);
        printf(" Element 6 is %d\n", sum[1][2]);
    }

    //But the answer shows 3 2 and 4 in the results .
    else {
        printf("re_entr the details\n");
        goto START;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The input was 2,2,2,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
output should be all 2 but it is not.
It shows 1 for half of the input.
pls help i am a begineer.
I believe the error is in the int k loop but unable to correct it.
I did try to tweak it a bit earlier but it jusst got worse.
https://code.sololearn.com/cN5V0DCdxufg

Comment: `int sum2;` is an *uninitialised variable* which you then do `sum2+= ...` to. Please turn on the compiler warnings. You reset it for the "next iteration" but not for the first. Better practice is to avoid "for the next..." and reset it just before you want to accumulate a value.

Comment: @WeatherVane I did that, vs is still not giving correct output.

Comment: The line `sum2 += (*ptr1[t5][k]) * (*ptr2[k][t6]);` assumes that `ptr1` (array `a`) can be indexed with `k` up to `r2` but that's the dimension of array `b`.

Comment: @WeatherVane value r2=c1 so will writing either of r2 or c1 create a problem?